# clGetProgramBuildInfo return empty string?

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to debug my code but the method clGetProgramBuildInfo with CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG parameter return an empty string, this is the code:

```
cl_int err;
cl_uint num_platforms;
err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &num_platforms);
cl_platform_id platform[num_platforms];
err = clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platform, NULL);
cl_uint num_devices;
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &num_devices);

cl_device_id device[num_devices];
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, num_devices, device, NULL);

cl_context context = clCreateContext(0, 1, device, NULL, NULL, &err);

string cl_str = util::loadProgram("vadd.cl");
const char * c = cl_str.c_str();
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource (    context,
                                                    1,
                                                    (const char **) &c,
                                                    NULL,
                                                    NULL);

err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

cl_char string[10240] = {0};
char* param_value;
clGetProgramBuildInfo (    program,
                           device[1],
                           CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                           10240,
                           string,
                           NULL);
cout << string << endl;
```

could you tell me what i do wrong? Thanks

Comment: Because this call returns a number, not a string? https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html

Comment: I edited the question CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sorry

Comment: You told clGetProgramBuildInfo that your buffer is 0 bytes long. Are you surprised it returns 0 bytes?

Comment: Also, you did not call clBuildProgram so there is no build information anyway.

Comment: ok, so i should call the method two time the method to get the size from the last parameter putting null the 4th and 5th and then calling another time the method with the parameter just obtained?

Comment: You should tell it how big `string` is, like the documentation says. Not how long the build log is, it knows that already. How long the variable `string` is.

Comment: I modified the program putting the length of the string and a clBuildProgram call but still i print an empty string..

Comment: Solved using a different device, the cpu instead of the gpu